# SwiftUI Toggle becomes disabled after pressing

Tags: ios, toggle, swiftui

I am struggling to get the correct behaviour from a toggle button in a user input form which controls part of the UI of the form. In the below code, the toggle button displays correctly based on which element of jobDetails is selected. 
However, switching the toggle button results in the toggle button becoming inactive/disabled for the rest of the session. I.e. the toggle button only works once. Obviously the desired behaviour is that the user should be able to toggle this at will.

This is the part of the code which is not working as expected.

```
struct AddShift_View: View {

    @State var index = 0
    @State var jobDetails: [JobDetails] = DataManager().fetchJobList()

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            Form {

                    Section(header: Text("Breaks")) {
                        Toggle(isOn: $jobDetails[index].hasAutomaticBreaks) {
                            Text("Automatic Breaks")
                        }
                    }

            } .navigationBarTitle(Text("Add Shift"))
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the relevant part of the `JobDetails` struct.

```
struct JobDetails: Codable, Identifiable, Equatable {

    // More properties here.

    var hasAutomaticBreaks: Bool

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code, and all is working well. The toggle button works as expected.
Don't forget to add an id in your JobDetails. Something like 
"var id = UUID()"

Maybe your problem is to do with the presumably async function 
DataManager().fetchJobList()

This is the test code I used with an async function.

```
    import SwiftUI

    struct JobDetails: Codable, Identifiable, Equatable {
       var id = UUID()
       var hasAutomaticBreaks: Bool
    }

    struct ContentView: View {
       @State var index = 0
       @State var jobDetails: [JobDetails] = []

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Breaks")) {
                    if jobDetails.count > 0 {
                        Toggle(isOn: $jobDetails[index].hasAutomaticBreaks) 
    {
                            Text("Automatic Breaks")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Add Shift"))
        }.onAppear(perform: fetchData)
    }

    func fetchData() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            self.jobDetails = [JobDetails(hasAutomaticBreaks: false)]
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this didn't exactly solve my issue but got me close enough to get there myself. The issue was in `JobDetails` conformance to `Equatable` via a custom implementation of the protocol method. Changing the `id` in `JobDetails` to `UUID` allowed me to get rid of the protocol method and everything then worked as expected. Thanks for your help.